# Look for previous working directory to implement "cd -"

Tags: java, shell, directory, cd

I am currently implementing a shell with limited functionality using Java programming language. The scope of the shell has restricted requirement too. The task is to model a Unix shell as much as I can.

When I am implementing the cd command option, I reference a [Basic Shell Commands page](http://www-xray.ast.cam.ac.uk/~jss/lecture/computing/notes/out/commands_basic/), it mentions that a cd is able to go back to the last directory I am in with the command "cd -".

As I am given only a interface with the method `public String execute(File presentWorkingDirectory, String stdin)`.

I will like to know if there is API call from Java which I can retrieve the previous working directory, or if there any implementation for this command?

I know one of the simple implementation is to declare a variable to store the previous working directory. However I am currently having the shell itself (the one that take in the command with options), and each time a command tool is executed, a new thread is created. Hence I do not think it is advisable for the "main" thread to store the previous working directory.

**Update (6-Mar-'14)**: Thank for the suggestion! I have now discussed with the coder for shell, and have added an additional variable to store the previous working directory. Below is the sample code for sharing:

```
public class CdTool extends ATool implements ICdTool {
    private static String previousDirectory;

    //Constructor
    /**
     * Create a new CdTool instance so that it represents an unexecuted cd command. 
     * 
     * @param arguments
     *  the argument that is to be passed in to execute the command
     */
    public CdTool(final String[] arguments) {
        super(arguments);
    }

    /**
     * Executes the tool with arguments provided in the constructor
     * 
     * @param workingDir
     *            the current working directory path
     * 
     * @param stdin
     *            the additional input from the stdin
     * 
     * @return the message to be shown on the shell, null if there is no error
     *         from the command
     */
    @Override
    public String execute(final File workingDir, final String stdin) {
        setStatusCode(0);
        String output = "";

        final String newDirectory;

        if(this.args[0] == "-" && previousDirectory != null){
            newDirectory = previousDirectory;
        }
        else{
            newDirectory = this.args[0];
        }

        if( !newDirectory.equals(workingDir) &&
            changeDirectory(newDirectory) == null){
            setStatusCode(DIRECTORY_ERROR_CODE);
        output = DIRECTORY_ERROR_MSG;
    }
    else{
        previousDirectory = workingDir.getAbsolutePath();
        output = changeDirectory(newDirectory).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    return output;
}

}
```

P.S: Please note that this is not the full implementation of the code, and this is not the full functionality of cd.

Comment: if you just want to have one level back, use a variable, if you want to have more levels back, maintain a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real shell (at least Bash) shell stores current working directory path in `PWD` environment variable and old working directory path in `OLDPWD`. Rewriting `PWD` does not change your working directory, but rewriting `OLDPWD` really changes where `cd -` will take you.

Try this:

```sh
cd /tmp
echo "$OLDPWD"          # /home/palec
export OLDPWD='/home'
cd -                    # changes working directory to /home
```

I don’t know how you implement the shell functionality (namely how you represent current working directory; usually it’s an inherent property of the process, implemented by the kernel) but **I think that you really have to keep the old working directory in an extra variable.**

By the way shell also forks for each command executed (except for the internal ones). Current working directory is a property of a process. When a command is started, it can change its inner current working directory, but it does not affect the shell’s one. Only `cd` command (which is internal) can change shell’s current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep more than one working directory just create a LinkedList where you add each new presentWorkingDirectory at the and and if you want to return use linkedList.popLast to get the last workingDirectory.

Comment: I think that the solution presented by @Kent in comment below the question is better. You should use stack to implement such a functionality. Stack is array-based, so it does not have overhead for pointers (references in this case) and node allocation (maybe they are pre-allocated somehow; don’t know Java’s guts that well).

Comment: True, that would do about the same. If you'd use ArrayLists then it would really be the same. I just figured a LinkedList would be quite useful since the length of the list might vary a lot, where LinkedLists are better than Array-Based lists/stacks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot what the stack is supposed to hold. Indeed, when remembering history of working directory changes, linked list is the best solution. If wanting to keep all the history – when only a fixed number of last working directories is needed, a circular buffer (array-based deque) is better.